# Py.test Python plugin doesn't add --clean to allure report generation

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pytest, allure

I have a Jenkins job that runs a shell command:

```
py.test -m smoke --environment=$ENVIRONMENT --alluredir="$WORKSPACE/allure-report"
```

But then when I build the Allure report as a post deploy step, I get an error:

```
Allure: Target directory <directory>/allure-report for the report is 
already in use, add a '--clean' option to overwrite
```

How do I pass --clean option to the post deploy step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to just clean up after myself and delete the directory so --clean isn't needed.